# v.generalize in QGIS throwing "Unable to create table" error

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, generalization

I am trying to smoothen few polyline shapefiles using v.generalize in QGIS 3.4. But it's not working. Even i tried the same in QGIS 2.18. Getting the same error.

[image]

Tried the same process in GRASS 7.4.2. The shapefile is not even getting loaded. When v.in.ogr is used, getting the exact "Unable to create table" error

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've created another field with name "Strm_Od" instead of order and deleted the "order" field after copying the attributes. Now, v.generalize command is running without any issues. Issue might be with the column name i guess

Comment: Yes, "ORDER" is an SQL reserved word, so you can't use it as an attribute name. Same with the words "SELECT", "UPDATE" etc...