# v.to.3d Fails in QGIS

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, vector

I've been able to use the vector to 3d tool successfully on some contour information before, but it's throwing an error anytime I work with data from New Hampshire's Granit site. In QGIS, the tool is processing contours that were clipped from a larger source, but the same error occurs with the original source.

The contour file was downloaded from [this site](ftp://ftp.granit.sr.unh.edu/pub/GRANIT_Data/Vector_Data/Elevation_and_Derived_Products/d-2ftcontours). Error log is below.

```
QGIS version: 3.14.16-Pi
QGIS code revision: df27394552
Qt version: 5.11.2
GDAL version: 3.0.4
GEOS version: 3.8.1-CAPI-1.13.3
PROJ version: Rel. 6.3.2, May 1st, 2020
Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'v.to.3d' starting…
Input parameters:
{ '-r' : False, '-t' : False, 'GRASS_MIN_AREA_PARAMETER' : 0.0001, 'GRASS_OUTPUT_TYPE_PARAMETER' : 0, 'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER' : None, 'GRASS_SNAP_TOLERANCE_PARAMETER' : -1, 'GRASS_VECTOR_DSCO' : '', 'GRASS_VECTOR_EXPORT_NOCAT' : False, 'GRASS_VECTOR_LCO' : '', 'column' : 'Contour', 'height' : None, 'input' : 'H:/Projects/1076 Davis Hill Rd/GIS/QGIS/clipped_contours.gpkg', 'output' : 'H:/Projects/1076 Davis Hill Rd/GIS/QGIS/3d_contours.shp', 'type' : [0,1,2,3] }

g.proj -c proj4="+proj=tmerc +lat_0=42.5 +lon_0=-71.6666666666667 +k=0.999966667 +x_0=300000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +units=us-ft +no_defs"
v.in.ogr min_area=0.0001 snap=-1.0 input="H:\Projects\1076 Davis Hill Rd\GIS\QGIS\clipped_contours.gpkg" output="vector_5fb6955ad4ece2" --overwrite -o
g.region n=535960.996313209 s=534763.830085938 e=1155883.30785149 w=1153276.4591556
v.to.3d input=vector_5fb6955ad4ece2 type="point,line,boundary,centroid" column=Contour output=outputa1606e472aa14d148dc8c5f860f34d52 --overwrite
v.out.ogr type="auto" input="outputa1606e472aa14d148dc8c5f860f34d52" output="H:\Projects\1076 Davis Hill Rd\GIS\QGIS\3d_contours.shp" format="ESRI_Shapefile" --overwrite
Starting GRASS GIS...
WARNING: Concurrent mapset locking is not supported on Windows
Cleaning up temporary files...
Executing <C:\Users\dylan.brown\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_YIrTJn\grassdata\grass_batch_job.cmd> ...
C:\Users\dylan.brown\Documents>chcp 1252 1>NUL
C:\Users\dylan.brown\Documents>g.proj -c proj4="+proj=tmerc +lat_0=42.5 +lon_0=-71.6666666666667 +k=0.999966667 +x_0=300000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +units=us-ft +no_defs"
WARNING: Datum <Unknown_based_on_GRS80_ellipsoid> not recognised by GRASS and no parameters found
Default region was updated to the new projection, but if you have multiple mapsets `g.region -d` should be run in each to update the region from the default
Projection information updated
C:\Users\dylan.brown\Documents>v.in.ogr min_area=0.0001 snap=-1.0 input="H:\Projects\1076 Davis Hill Rd\GIS\QGIS\clipped_contours.gpkg" output="vector_5fb6955ad4ece2" --overwrite -o
Over-riding projection check
Check if OGR layer <clipped_contours> contains polygons...
0..2..4..6..8..10..12..14..16..18..20..22..24..26..28..30..32..34..36..38..40..42..44..46..48..50..52..54..56..58..60..62..64..66..68..70..72..74..76..78..80..82..84..86..88..90..92..94..96..98..100
Creating attribute table for layer <clipped_contours>...
ERROR: Unable to create table: 'create table vector_5fb6955ad4ece2 (cat integer, OBJECTID integer, Id integer, Contour double precision, INDEX integer, Shape_Length double precision)'
C:\Users\dylan.brown\Documents>g.region n=535960.996313209 s=534763.830085938 e=1155883.30785149 w=1153276.4591556
C:\Users\dylan.brown\Documents>v.to.3d input=vector_5fb6955ad4ece2 type="point,line,boundary,centroid" column=Contour output=outputa1606e472aa14d148dc8c5f860f34d52 --overwrite
WARNING: Coor file of vector map <vector_5fb6955ad4ece2@PERMANENT> is larger than it should be (18 bytes excess)
ERROR: Column <Contour> not found in table <vector_5fb6955ad4ece2>
WARNING: Unable to delete file 'C:\Users\dylan.brown\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_YIrTJn\grassdata\temp_location\PERMANENT\vector/outputa1606e472aa14d148dc8c5f860f34d52/coor'
C:\Users\dylan.brown\Documents>v.out.ogr type="auto" input="outputa1606e472aa14d148dc8c5f860f34d52" output="H:\Projects\1076 Davis Hill Rd\GIS\QGIS\3d_contours.shp" format="ESRI_Shapefile" --overwrite
WARNING: Unable to open vector map <outputa1606e472aa14d148dc8c5f860f34d52@PERMANENT> on level 2. Try to rebuild vector topology with v.build.
ERROR: Unable to open vector map <outputa1606e472aa14d148dc8c5f860f34d52>
C:\Users\dylan.brown\Documents>exit
Execution of <C:\Users\dylan.brown\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_YIrTJn\grassdata\grass_batch_job.cmd> finished.
Cleaning up default sqlite database ...
Cleaning up temporary files...
Press any key to continue . . .
Execution completed in 2.58 seconds
Results:
{'output': 'H:\\Projects\\1076 Davis Hill Rd\\GIS\\QGIS\\3d_contours.shp'}

Loading resulting layers
The following layers were not correctly generated.
• H:/Projects/1076 Davis Hill Rd/GIS/QGIS/3d_contours.shp
You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.
```

Log Messages
Plugins

```
2020-11-19T11:17:22     INFO    Loaded DB Manager (package: db_manager)
2020-11-19T11:17:23     INFO    Loaded MetaSearch Catalog Client (package: MetaSearch)
2020-11-19T11:17:27     INFO    Loaded Processing (package: processing)
```

Python Warning

```
2020-11-19T11:17:23     WARNING    warning:C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.14/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py:792: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
              mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
             
             traceback: File "", line 1, in 
              File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.14/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 302, in loadPlugin
              __import__(packageName)
              File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.14/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 792, in _import
              mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
              File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
              File "", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
              File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked
              File "", line 728, in exec_module
              File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
              File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.14/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\__init__.py", line 26, in 
              from processing.tools.general import * # NOQA
              File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.14/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 792, in _import
              mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
              File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
              File "", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
              File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked
              File "", line 728, in exec_module
              File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
              File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.14/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 32, in 
              from processing.core.Processing import Processing
              File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.14/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 792, in _import
              mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
              File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
              File "", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
              File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked
              File "", line 728, in exec_module
              File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
              File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.14/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 56, in 
              from processing.algs.qgis.QgisAlgorithmProvider import QgisAlgorithmProvider # NOQA
              File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.14/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 792, in _import
              mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
              File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
              File "", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
              File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked
              File "", line 728, in exec_module
              File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
              File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.14/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\QgisAlgorithmProvider.py", line 51, in 
              from .HypsometricCurves import HypsometricCurves
              File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.14/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 792, in _import
              mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
              File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
              File "", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
              File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked
              File "", line 728, in exec_module
              File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
              File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.14/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\HypsometricCurves.py", line 27, in 
              from osgeo import gdal, ogr, osr
              File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.14/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 792, in _import
              mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
              File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
              File "", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
              File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked
              File "", line 728, in exec_module
              File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
              File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.14\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 41, in 
              _gdal = swig_import_helper()
              File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.14\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 15, in swig_import_helper
              import imp
              File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.14/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 792, in _import
              mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
              File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
              File "", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
              File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked
              File "", line 728, in exec_module
              File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
              File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.14\apps\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 33, in 
              DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2)
```

General

```
2020-11-19T11:17:27     INFO    Application state:
             QGIS_PREFIX_PATH env var: C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.14/apps/qgis
             Prefix: C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.14/apps/qgis
             Plugin Path: C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.14/apps/qgis/plugins
             Package Data Path: C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.14/apps/qgis/.
             Active Theme Name: default
             Active Theme Path: C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.14/apps/qgis/./resources/themes\default\icons/
             Default Theme Path: :/images/themes/default/
             SVG Search Paths: C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./svg/
              C:/Users/dylan.brown/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/svg/
              C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.14/apps/qgis/./svg/
             User DB Path: C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.14/apps/qgis/./resources/qgis.db
             Auth DB Path: C:/Users/dylan.brown/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/qgis-auth.db
```

Grass

```
2020-11-19T11:17:58     INFO    processInputs end. Commands: ['g.proj -c proj4="+proj=tmerc +lat_0=42.5 +lon_0=-71.6666666666667 +k=0.999966667 +x_0=300000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +units=us-ft +no_defs"', 'v.in.ogr min_area=0.0001 snap=-1.0 input="H:\\Projects\\1076 Davis Hill Rd\\GIS\\QGIS\\clipped_contours.gpkg" output="vector_5fb69ab676c552" --overwrite -o', 'g.region n=535960.996313209 s=534763.830085938 e=1155883.30785149 w=1153276.4591556']
2020-11-19T11:17:58     INFO    processCommands end. Commands: ['g.proj -c proj4="+proj=tmerc +lat_0=42.5 +lon_0=-71.6666666666667 +k=0.999966667 +x_0=300000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +units=us-ft +no_defs"', 'v.in.ogr min_area=0.0001 snap=-1.0 input="H:\\Projects\\1076 Davis Hill Rd\\GIS\\QGIS\\clipped_contours.gpkg" output="vector_5fb69ab676c552" --overwrite -o', 'g.region n=535960.996313209 s=534763.830085938 e=1155883.30785149 w=1153276.4591556', 'v.to.3d input=vector_5fb69ab676c552 type="point,line,boundary,centroid" column=Contour output=output16a56bda1ca644b18912e586081cb353 --overwrite']
```

Comment: Any additional info in the `Log Messages Panel`?

Comment: I just added more log info at the end of the post.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is here:

> ERROR: Unable to create table: 'create table vector_5fb6955ad4ece2
> (cat integer, OBJECTID integer, Id integer, Contour double precision,
> INDEX integer, Shape_Length double precision)'

It cannot create the table because of the field named `'INDEX'`, which is an SQL reserved word (see comment [on this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/321182/142299) and [here](https://docs.actian.com/zen/v14/index.html#page/sqlref/sqlkword.htm) for a list of reserved words). Delete that field and it will run.

Comment: Thanks, that did it. For some reason it didn't work on the first four attempts, but after that, the command was able to process the contours.